# Does Python3 str class have an internal bytes object as member variable?

Tags: python-3.x, string, unicode

**NOTE:** This thread is about the internal implementation of str in CPython, especially Python 3.7.3 onwards.

I know that Python 3's str type can contain any Unicode character with default UTF-8 encoding attached to it.

Imagine we have:

```
s = "Δv / Δt"
s.encode('utf-8')         # returning
b'\xce\x94v / \xce\x94t'  # UTF-8 encoded
```

**I wonder, how str type is implemented to hold the UTF-8 encoded characters in binary?**

**Q1)** My assumption is that Python3 str should store UTF-8 encoded values in an instance variable; i.e. str class has an internal bytes object (lets call it **i_bytes**), which stores UTF-8 encoded bytes '\xce\x94v / \xce\x94t'. str class should also store the encoding type "defaults to utf-8" in another instance variable (lets call it **i_encoding**). Is this understanding correct?

**Q2)** Is **repr**() implementation of str like this?

```
class str:
    def __repr__(self):
         return self.i_bytes.decode(self.i_encoding)
```

P.S I am a newbie when it comes to these advanced concepts, so please try to explain as simple as possible. Thanks for the help

Comment: See [PEP 393 -- Flexible String Representation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/) for a description of the current implementation.